# Trying to draw a quantum circuit, a basic one

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, quantikz, qcircuit

In the beginning, it can start with 'n' input and the same number of output but could not make output lines. I am actually now quite sure about the details of these codes, that's why could not increase the input numbers too.
I tried to draw on it (see the image), but the circles are not a must.
And if it is possible I would like to write 'environment' under the box of errors.
Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,twocolumn,aps,pra, superscriptaddress,longbibliography]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\captionsetup{
  subrefformat=parens
}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand\frontmatter@abstractwidth{\dimexpr\textwidth\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{quantikz}
& \gate[wires=3][1.5cm]{encode}
        \gateoutput[wires=1]{} & \gate[wires=3][1.5cm]{errors} & \gate[wires=3][1.5cm]{recovery} & \gate[wires=3][1.5cm]{decode}\\
            &\gateinput{} & & &\qw \\
            &\gateoutput{}& & &\qw \\
\end{quantikz}
\caption{The journey of quantum data.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the arrows on the right, you can add `\arrow[thick, r] &` to each row. You need the `&` as an extra column so the arrow can point to something.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{quantikz}
& \gate[wires=3][1.5cm]{encode}
        \gateoutput[wires=1]{} & \gate[wires=3][1.5cm]{errors} & \gate[wires=3][1.5cm]{recovery} & \gate[wires=3][1.5cm]{decode}\arrow[thick, r] & \\
            &\gateinput{} & & &\qw\arrow[thick, r] & \\
            &\gateoutput{}& & &\qw\arrow[thick, r] & \\
\end{quantikz}
\caption{The journey of quantum data.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You might consider just using basic Ti*k*Z for your other requirements:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [thick, mybox/.style={fill=white, draw, minimum height=2cm, pos=#1, font=\itshape}, minimum width=15mm]
\draw[{Circle[open]}->](0,.7)--(8,.7);
\draw[{Circle[open]}->](0,-.7)--(8,-.7);
\draw[{Circle[open]}->](0,0)--node[mybox=.14]{encode}node[mybox=.38](errors){errors}node[mybox=.62]{recovery}node[mybox=.86]{decode}(8,0);
\node[below] at (errors.south){environment};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The journey of quantum data.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your help. Of course, I draw them like arrows, they suppose to circle too :)
But thanks to you, I could fix it :)

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [thick, mybox/.style={fill=white, draw, minimum height=2cm, pos=#1, font=\itshape}, minimum width=15mm]
\draw[{Circle[open]}-{Circle[open]}](0,.7)--(8,.7);
\draw[{Circle[open]}-{Circle[open]}](0,-.7)--(8,-.7);
\draw[{Circle[open]}-{Circle[open]}](0,0)--node[mybox=.14]{encode}node[mybox=.38](errors){errors}node[mybox=.62]{recovery}node[mybox=.86]{decode}(8,0);
\node[below] at (errors.south){environment};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The journey of quantum data.}
\end{figure}
```